# TOAD(11.5) - DB Connection fails with 'protocol adapter not loadable' , windows 10

Tags: windows-10, oracle-11g, oracle-database, oracle-12c, toad

It all started with me trying to import 11g db dump into 12c R2 oracle.

DB Dump - 11.02.0 
Server - 12.2.0.1.0

I was getting the tns error
'could not resolve connect identifier specified'. After some research , I fixed it by adding oracle home to system variables.

Then Import command started giving 'protocol adapter not loadable error' (and same with Toad(11.5)), which I fixed by putting Oracle home path in path variable before client path variable.

After that , import using IMP command started to work but when I launch toad (which was working before adding oracle home and not after doing so) ,enter db details and hit connect, it keeps failing with a popup showing  'protocol adapter not loadable'.

Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses.

I removed ORACLE_HOME and moved path to server above path to oracle client in path variable. Now, as I had to add oracle_home to fix the listener issue for which  I just dropped and created new listener on 1521 using net configuration utility that comes with oracle(I also have an entry in tnsnames.ora). It is all working just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle article
[ORA-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12577.htm)
advises:

> There are two solutions to this issue:
>
> 1. Put the Oracle DB Home in front of the other paths in the PATH environment variable.
> 2. Remove ORACLE_HOME From environment Variable and re-boot PC

Solution 1 seems to say that the order of the items in the PATH variable does matter
here.
It is required that the Oracle DB Home be placed in front of the
Oracle Client Home.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it fixed the error with IMP (import). But toad still giving the error.

Comment: Also, I added oracle home because of the first error I was getting while importing the db as mentioned in the question.

Comment: What is the error code that arrives with the message of "protocol adapter not loadable"?

Comment: error code is  ORA-12557 TNS:......

Comment: Do you maybe have a mixup of 32- and 64-bit software?

Comment: Yes, I have 64 bit oracle server and 32 bit client, as we do not support 64 bit client machines for our product.

Comment: 32-bit should come first in PATH. If you have an Oracle account, this [support document](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1516753_1.html) may have the solution. Not having such an account, I can't verify it.